# Trying to put a css background image to the main menu

Tags: css

Hi i would like to show up an image

```
background-image: url("../images/frame.png");
```

in the background of the main menu, but i am not able to make it fit correctly.

I am absolutely stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: check out https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @Nicholas That is not at all what he is trying to accomplish

Comment: @GustvandeWal
Well, initially i have chuckled at this, but preciselly the above article and some random other have been my "breakthrough" back in the day when image stuff seemed incomprehensible to me:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for background images, if you do not use img tags, is the following, imo, because its responsive and consistent.

```
your element{
background-image:
url("../images/frame.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Apply this to you element of choice and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it actually works :) but i think it would be better if the images could have fixed length. How exactly do i do that?

Comment: You mean fixed width? Just add this to the above(don't change anything above):
width: min-width: your number;
text-align:center;

this will always keep a minimum width on any scren size and because the text in your links is of variable lenght and the link backgrounds will be same width now, you will want to have centered text.

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you so much. I was stuck for hours :)

Comment: @ArFoul
An time:-)
For me, placing images correctly, background properties etc was initially more confusing than later on building a 3d cube.
The one css thing which will make you weed out many doubts is, think of css as an asignment tool for rectangles, everything is a rectangle in css with some properties attached to it:-)

Answer (score -1):

Try editing the css from 40px to this:

```
.uk-navbar-nav > li > a {
    height: 57px;
}
```